# Conditional in keras model based on input data / features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model which I would like to accept two input features, each feature would be encoded via its own embedding and dense layers. The two features are then summed to create the final output.

Dataset:

```
row1 -> {x1: 'tag', x2: null, y: 'y1'}
row2 -> {x1: null, x2: 'long text field', y: 'y2'}
```

No rows contain both `x1` and `x2`, so the part of the model which encodes each feature needs to see the empty value and return a vector of zeros.

For the long text field I am not using my own model, but rather a pre-trained LM, this means I cannot add a special token to return all zeros - the tokenizer and embeddings are fixed.

How would I add a conditional into the model, which when the data is zero would skip the layer and return zeros, allowing me to just sum the outputs of the two towers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hacky fix for this...

I am reading inputs of `''` so empty strings inside of the model class, and added a custom call to mask out values:

```py
def call(self, inputs):
    outputs = self.model(inputs)
    boolean_mask = tf.equal(inputs, tf.constant(''))
    boolean_mask = tf.reshape(boolean_mask, [-1, 1])
    zeros = tf.zeros_like(outputs)
    return tf.where(boolean_mask, zeros, outputs)
```

I assume there is a better way and would love to hear it!